# Movie about a young boy and girl who escape from underground to the surface

Tags: story-identification, movie, underground-civilization

Plot elements:

- Families live underground, contact is forbidden, but the protagonist kids want to meet and eventually also escape to the surface, which seems to be a desert.
- The air is breathable, contrary to what they are told.
- The boy and girl communicate through a big screen, which takes up almost the whole wall. (As do the aduls too with other adults of other groups/families.)
- It's probably a dystopian sci-fi, so tunnels instead of caves and no magic.
- I very faintly remember some kind of slide/capsule system for transportation, but this might just be my brain trying to come up with details that are simply incorrect.

I saw this in Hungarian sometime in the early 90s (not in a cinema, so it's probably made in the 80s). So this could be a B-movie, a direct to VHS TV show, or who knows what.

---

It's not *City of Ember*.

Comment: Are you sure it's not City of Ember? :-)

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question is very terse (and tropey) and would be greatly improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) to identify anything else you can remember about the film, its actors, dialogue, setting, etc

Comment: I wanted to double check before it turns out I'm a dum-dum, but the City of Ember novel was published in 2003, huh. Sureness preserved :)

Alas I don't remember much - and I fear that adding anything else would just make people try to filter out their guesses. :(

Comment: Fair enough. Thought I'd check.

Comment: Well, for example, what can you tell us about these teens? Boy and girl? Two girls? Two boys? Multiples of each? How old? Caucasian? Approx age? Famous?

Comment: Underground like in caves? Like concrete tunnels? Like a gigantic facility? What were they eating? What kind of lighting was it? What was the film budget like? Aimed at adults or kids? Any violence or nudity?

Comment: Boy and girl, as indicated in the title. ~10-16 year olds. (I vaguely recall they are of similar age probably because the whole escape thing gets triggered because they are in love. But, sorry, I wrote this after looking through all the other underground movie identification questions, and many other "similar to" sites on the net.)

Comment: Tunnels were involved, yes! I had no idea what they eat. I don't recall caves. I'm pretty sure there was no nudity, and probably no violence either.

Comment: We're usually pretty good at considering that not all details are correct, so please provide any detail you can. If you're not certain on a point, just say as much.

Comment: Elements of this match Logan's Run

Answer (score 6):

I've already answered [a similar question someplace else](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/24155/post-apocalyptic-movie-with-people-living-underground/24166#24166), so I might as well put it up here too.

This matches all the plot elements of [**Fuga dal paradiso**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099621/) *(AKA Flight\Escape from Paradise)*, an obscure Italian sci-fi film from 1990. From an IMDb review:

> **[A ]film that takes place sometime in the future after an ecological disaster has occurred. [...] The tale concerns two young people, Teo and Beatrice, whom live apart in an underground vault.** Their separation is not by choice however, since this vault is governed by a computer named Harry - it decides which males and females are compatible to be paired together. **Of course, Teo & Beatrice are very much in love and wish to be together**, but doubt whether Harry will give them its blessing. **The two can see each other on view screens, and neither having seen the outside world, only experience a limited controlled version of it** through holographic simulations, in one scene it appears Teo is running on a tread-mill while Beatrice is running along a field on-screen [...] Together with the help of a robot (think Buck Rogers '81 season two) **Teo and Beatrice find a way out of their designated sectors to the ruined world above.**

Also tunnels are involved, IIRC they can breathe the air after all, etc. Here are the two progtagonists:

[image]