# 80/90's movie – community living a bunker, separated by families, youth pair escapes

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

There was a movie in 80's or 90's in TV that I'm trying to identify. The key points were:

- people are living in a kind of bunker, separated by families, supplies are delivered from outside
- pair of young people meet by a kind of Skype
- they watch recordings with a lot of people together (stolen from fathers memory device)
- they decide to escape and to live outside

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the 1990 Italian sci-fi film [Fuga dal paradiso AKA Flight\Escape from Paradise](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099621/) again (I already answered a couple of similar questions, one of them [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/215224/movie-about-a-young-boy-and-girl-who-escape-from-underground-to-the-surface)). It's about people living underground in a post-apocalyptic world, and a young couple who communicate through screens that decide to escape together and reach the surface.

Here's the cover (from imdb):

[image]