# Book about a boy living in a futuristic building underground because of toxic air at the surface

Tags: story-identification, books, post-apocalyptic, dystopia, underground-civilization

I've been searching for this book for years but still no clues today. I think I read it in high school so it must be between 2012-2014. I don't remember if it was an old or modern book, but here is what I recall for sure:

This is the story of a young boy living underground with his mother or aunt. Everything is white and in their house the walls can open and close to stock items or whatever, so it's super high tech.

Later he meets a girl and they slowly get the idea to go outside, thinking adults were lying and that the Earth wasn't as toxic as they were claiming. Escape and chase ensue, then one moment we learn they value the MC because he appears to be very fertile for future generations. Yep, that was weird but it's true.

One moment they managed to open the door leading outside but discovered a completely desolate land.
Much later at the end, they did it again and this time they could breathe the outside air without dying or something like this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You've tagged this with both "dystopia" and "post-apocalyptic."  Most post-apocalyptic worlds are crapsack, but not necessarily dystopian thereby.  Was there something more about the world that specifically made it a dystopia?

Comment: Sounds a lot like https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/215224/movie-about-a-young-boy-and-girl-who-escape-from-underground-to-the-surface?rq=1, but that's a film.

Comment: Probably not George Bamber's 1971 eco-jeremiad _[The Sea Is Boiling Hot](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/1550192)_.

Comment: @Spencer indeed, this is not the one sadly...